# Java filecopy with the same speed (USB2 -> USB3 on Linux server). What's wrong?

Tags: java, linux, usb, file-copying

I have a very simple file copy in Java. It is copies the DB file about 6 minutes to my external (usb3) HDD.

```
//First database:
try {
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedfile);
bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
outputFile = new File("" + chosenDestination);
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
size = selectedfile.length();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 6];
dbLabel.setText("Copying Database...");
while ((data = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, data);
        total += data;
        String percent = "" + total / (size / 100);
        pbar.setValue(Integer.valueOf(percent));
        sizeLabel.setText("(" + total / (1024 * 1024) + " / " + (size / (1024 * 1024)) + " MB) ");
    }
} finally {
     bufferedOutputStream.close();
     fileInputStream.close();
     fileOutputStream.close();
     bufferedInputStream.close();
}
```

Yesterday I bought a Transcend TS-PDU3 (PCI-E) USB additon card. So my computer and my HDD are able to USB3 too. But when I tried the copyjob, it is copy the file with same speed. It is a Linux server so don't need driver (lspci see it) and I think everything work good so I think the error is in the java code. What buffer size I need to choose for USB3. Is the 6 * 1024 is a small buffer size. Or I need to search the error in elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use NIO instead of streams? Also, why `"" + chosenDestination`? What is `chosenDestination`?

Comment: NIO? I don't know what is it. Can you explain it?

Comment: OK, first things first: do you use Java 7?

Comment: Have you testing copying speeds using file system tools? USB3 should be significantly faster, but it would be worth testing this outside the context of your Java application before you assume your code is at fault.

Comment: Actually you have at least three buffers and it is more likely to be slowing you down than speeding you up.  I would use just one buffer and get rid of the Buffered*Streams.  I would also try a buffer of 32 KB.

Comment: Also why would you change an `int` into a `String` and then change it back into an `int` again.  I suspect the simplest way to speed up your code is to remove redundant effort.

Comment: Duncan: I'll test it.
Peter Lawrey: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use Java 7, you have a much easier way to copy data from one file to another. With NIO, you can do that:

```
final Path src = Paths.get(selectedFile);
final Path dst = Paths.get(outputFile);

Files.copy(src, dst);
```

The JVM does a pretty good job at that. If you don't see an improvement from your current code, well... Replace your code with this first, and investigate further. As you said, no specific drivers are needed in theory.

Comment: I'm use Java 7 of course, but I need a progress bar and I am not wrong, It isn't work this way. Am I right?